# Two different custom user detail services for two different URL patterns

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-4

Can I use, two different `custom user detail services` for 2 different URL patterns.
I want to use 2 different user detail services because there are 2 database, and authentication should happen against 1 or the other, but the selection of the user detail service bean depends on the URL pattern.

Is there a way to do this?

Or I may be looking to solve above problem in a wrong way.

Appreciate if anyone could help.

Uses Spring 4.1.6, Spring Security 4.0, Java Configs.

Comment: you can have multiple authenticationManagers in one authenticationProvider

Comment: Neil - but he should be careful with bean ids, so they don't duplicate. Right?

Comment: @Neil Can provide some resource/example ?

Comment: With 2 providers, I saw it executes both, if the first failed. And also the order is important. But what I want is providerX should only work for URL pattern X and providerY should only work for URL pattern Y. It shouldn't happen this: if providerX failed then provideY

Comment: oh ok. can you not setup two `<http>` sections in spring security?

Comment: I did it using 2 inner classes which extend `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` with `@Configuration` and `@Order`. Then added providers for both adapters. However both the providers execute one after other.